# Need Help Creating a specific kind of Isotope Plot in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I hope that you are doing well. I am currently trying to replicate a type of isotope plot that's common in my field. Essentially, it's the result of a compound-specific stable isotope analysis.

The x and y axes represent delta values that are plotted against isotopic references from animals (ellipses) to identify animals by their signature. The ellipses represent a 95% CI.

I'm a beginner in R. I've managed to get the scatter plot to work, but I don't understand how to create a CI ellipses with reference data. Would anyone here know how to do this?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dngMC.png)

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please make your question reproducible: include a minimal dataset in the form of an object for example if a data frame as df <- data.frame(…) where … is your variables and values or use dput(head(df)). Also include the code you have tried. Check out [mre] and [ask]

Comment: Try this site to see if there is an extension already https://exts.ggplot2.tidyverse.org/gallery/